# Laravel 5.2: Display a session flash message after user login/logout and registration

Tags: php, flash, authentication, laravel-5, notifications

Working with the default setup generated after running `php artisan make:auth`, I am now wondering how do I control the flash messages I need to show to a user when he logs in.

So far I have tried adding this code to the default `AuthController`:

```
 public function authenticated($request, $user)
    {
        flash('Welcome back ' . $user->username . ', you have been logged in');
    }
```

But this causes too many redirects error in my Chrome browser. How do I flash custom messages without creating a custom `LoginController` or overriding the complete `login` method inside `AuthController`?

Comment: Check the `/app/resources/lang/en/auth.php` file for some of them. Not sure if they are all customizable there, or if some are hard coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to override the following methods in my `AuthController`:

```
/**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $successmessage = 'you are now successfully registered!';
        flash()->overlay('Yes', $successmessage, 'success');
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

    }

    /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        flash()->info('Bye', 'You have been successfully logged out!');
        return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
    }

    /**
     * Function called after user logs in
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function authenticated() {
        $successmessage = 'Hej '.Auth::user()->name.', you are logged in!';
        flash()->success('Hello', $successmessage);
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

That's it! Note that I am using a custom flash setup. You can use the defaults or your own

Answer (score 2):

### Laravel 5.4

#### login/logout

Copy `authenticated` and `logout` method from `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php`.
Paste to `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`.
Add flash message.
Don't forget to import `Illuminate\Http\Request`.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        return redirect('users/' . $user->id)->with('status', __('You logged in.'));
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        $request->session()->flush();
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect('/')->with('status', __('You logged out.'));
    }
```

#### register

Copy `registered` method from `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php`.
Paste to `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php`.
Add flash message.
Don't forget to import `Illuminate\Http\Request`.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * The user has been registered.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        return redirect('users/' . $user->id)->with('status', __('You were registered.'));
    }
```